# Customization of GraphiQL interface in Spring-Boot project

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, graphiql

According to the GraphiQL [README](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) I can customize the interface by adding React `children` like this:

```
<GraphiQL.Logo>
    My Custom Logo
</GraphiQL.Logo>
```

That is great, but how do I actually set these children? I'm not a web developer and I've never used React before! I'm developing a Spring-Boot project with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't see any way to set the children via `application.properties/yml`, although I can set other things there like the `pageTitle`, `defaultQuery` and `editorTheme`.

I can override the `graphiql.html` page provided by the starter. I naively tried to set the children like this at the end of the page:

```
// Render <GraphiQL /> into the body.
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(GraphiQL, props, [React.createElement('GraphiQL.Logo', {}, 'Custom LOGO')]),
    document.body
);
```

That didn't have any effect.

How should I approach this?

Comment: I didn’t find a solution yet.